# Cannot unpack tuple object in FOR loop Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, iterable-unpacking

Here is the code:

```
for m, n in ("example_string", True):
    print(m, n)
```

This code doesn't work. Interpreter says:
[image]

## But how to unpack this 2-items tuple in `FOR` loop?

Desirable output is:

> example_string True

Comment: `m,n = ("example_string", True)` ? or `for m,n in (("example_string", True),)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unpack it first.

```
m, n = ("example_string", True)
```

If the tuple contained iterables itself, then you could unpack it in the loop:

```
for m, n in (('x','y'), (x,y)):  # this works
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't iterate over a 2-length tuple and unpack it into a tuple at the same time. Try this:

```
m, n  = ("example_string", True)
print(m, n)
```

If you want to unpack your tuple inside the for-loop, each item in the iterable must be a 2-tuple.

```
for m,n in [(1,2), (3,4)]:
    print(m,n)
```

This would print:

```
1 2
3 4
```